Is there a way to read an .egp file without using SAS Entreprise Guide?
I want to scan using Python a folder containing hundreds of .sas and .egp files.
The .sas files are not a problem since I can simply read them like that :
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='latin-1') as f:
    ...

But since .egp files do not allow this technique, I use this function to extract the scripts from the archive so that I can then read them:
def extract_sas_scripts_from_egp(file_path):
    scripts = []
    extraction_dir = file_path.replace('.egp', '_extracted')

    # Reset Extraction Folder
    if os.path.exists(extraction_dir):
        for file in os.listdir(extraction_dir):
            os.remove(os.path.join(extraction_dir, file))
    else:
        os.makedirs(extraction_dir)

    # Extract .sas files from the archive
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, 'r') as archive:
        for file_info in archive.infolist():
            if file_info.filename.endswith(".sas"):
                extracted_path = os.path.join(extraction_dir, os.path.basename(file_info.filename))
                with archive.open(file_info) as sas_file:
                    content = sas_file.read().decode('latin-1')
                    scripts.append((content, extracted_path))
                    with open(extracted_path, 'w', encoding='latin-1') as f:
                        f.write(content)
    return scripts

My problem is that the generated "_extracted" folder seems to contain only the first .sas script, leaving out all the others I also need.

Questions :

Do you know why my script gives this result and how I can make sure to see all my scripts?
Do you know any other method to read .egp files?

Thank you!


I think this is because all the sas files embedded in an EGP file are named "code.sas". So I expect the extracted file keeps getting overwritten by your code.

Each of the "code.sas" files is in a separate folder inside the EGP archive. To get the relevant folders, you need to parse the project.xml file in the top level of the archive:

Look for <NodeType> elements containing the text NODETYPE_PROGRAMFOLDER.
These represent process flows and the <EGTreeNode> siblings of this element represent SAS programs.

Within these <EGTreeNode> elements, nodes named <ElementID> should contain the folder name where the code.sas file is located. And nodes named <Label> should contain the program name. (You can use this to rename code.sas after you've extracted it.)




I have used this method to extract SAS programs from EGP files for Enterprise Guide 7.1 and 5.1 (for version 5.1, I seem to remember the <Label> contains the full file path instead of the program name, so I had to do a bit more processing for those). Enterprise Guide 4.1 files have a different structure, so need a slightly different process.
I have done this using R and SAS code, but unfortunately not with python, so I can't recommend any packages/functions for parsing the XML.
Edit: An attempt at a python function for this task
This approach creates a sub-folder for each process flow - otherwise there will be a problem if 2 process flows have SAS programs with the same name.
I suspect this can be done much more elegantly (without all the re-naming and deleting), but this version has worked on a selection of Enterprise Guide 7.1 projects:
import os
import zipfile
import lxml.etree as ET
import shutil

def extract_sas_scripts_from_egp(file_path):
    scripts = []
    extraction_dir = file_path.replace('.egp', '_extracted')

    # Reset Extraction Folder
    if os.path.exists(extraction_dir):
        for file in os.listdir(extraction_dir):
            os.remove(os.path.join(extraction_dir, file))
    else:
        os.makedirs(extraction_dir)

    # Reference to the EGP file
    egp = zipfile.ZipFile(file_path, "r")
    # Read the info from project.xml
    tree = ET.parse(egp.open("project.xml"))
    # Extract the process flows
    process_flows = [elem for elem in tree.iter() if elem.text == "NODETYPE_PROGRAMFOLDER"]
    # Extract the elements relating to process flows
    programs = [elem for flow in process_flows for elem in flow.xpath("following-sibling::EGTreeNode")]
    # ElementID elements contain the name of each folder inside the EGP containing code.sas
    folders = [element.text for program in programs for element in program.xpath("ElementID")]
    # Label elements contain the program name (used to rename the extracted files later)
    names = [element.text for program in programs for element in program.xpath("Label")]
    # Unique names of process flows (used to create directories later)
    pfnames_unique = [elem.text for process in process_flows for elem in
               process.xpath("./parent::EGTreeNode/parent::EGTreeNode/Label")]
    # Names of process flows (one for each program)
    pfnames = [elem.text for program in programs for elem in
               program.xpath("./parent::EGTreeNode/parent::EGTreeNode/Label")]
    # Path to code.sas files within the EGP archive
    sasfiles = [folder + "/code.sas" for folder in folders]
    # The relevant process flow folder to extract each code.sas file to
    extracted_folders = [os.path.join(extraction_dir, folder) for folder in pfnames]
    # The path to the extracted code.sas files (used to rename these later)
    extracted_files = [os.path.join(extraction_dir, pfnames, sasfile) for sasfile, pfnames in zip(sasfiles, pfnames)]
    # The desired paths and names for the extracted sas files
    extracted_files_rename = [os.path.join(extraction_dir, pfnames, name + ".sas") for name, pfnames in zip(names, pfnames)]
    # List of extracted directories to be deleted at the end
    new_dirs = [os.path.join(extraction_dir, pf, fol) for pf, fol in zip(pfnames, folders)]
    # New directories to create (one for each process flow)
    new_dirs_unique = [os.path.join(extraction_dir, pf) for pf in pfnames_unique]

    print(sasfiles)
    print(extracted_folders)

    print(extracted_files)
    print(extracted_files_rename)
    print(extracted_folders)
    print(new_dirs)
    print(new_dirs_unique)

    # Create the directories for each process flow in the output directory
    for new_dir in new_dirs_unique:
        os.makedirs(new_dir)

    # Extract the code.sas files. These will be extracted along with their parent
    # directory inside the archive, so we will have to rename them later, and delete the directory.
    # the try...except is for cases where there is no code.sas file - this happens if a program is
    # linked rather than embedded in the EGP
    for file, newfile in zip(sasfiles, extracted_folders):
        try:
            egp.extract(file, newfile)
        except:
            print("Unable to extract " + file)

    # Rename to move the sas files to their correct location
    for oldname, newname in zip(extracted_files, extracted_files_rename):
        try:
            os.rename(oldname, newname)
        except:
            pass

    # Delete the unwanted directories
    for dir in new_dirs:
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(dir)
        except:
            pass
 
 

